# OpenGL texture repeat artifacts

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, textures, opengl-4

I'm using OpenGL (4.5 core, with LWJGL 3.0.0 build 90) and I noticed some artifacts on textures using `GL_REPEAT` wrap mode with a high amount of repetitions:

[image: Texture artifacts]

### What causes this, and how can I fix it (if I can) ?

---

Here, the plane's size is 100x100, and the UVs are 10000x10000. This screenshot is really really close to it (from farther, the texture is so small that we just see a flat gray color), the near plane is at 0.0001 and the far plane at 10.
I'm not sure if the problem is in the Depth Buffer since the OpenGL default one has a really high precision at closer distances.

(**EDIT:** I'm thinking of a floating point error on texture coordinates, but I'm not sure)

Here's my shader (I'm using deferred rendering, and the texture sampling is in the geometry pass, so I give the geometry pass shader only).

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 450 core

uniform mat4 projViewModel;
uniform mat4 viewModel;
uniform mat3 normalView;

in vec3 normal_model;
in vec3 position_model;
in vec2 uv;
in vec2 uv2;

out vec3 pass_position_view;
out vec3 pass_normal_view;
out vec2 pass_uv;
out vec2 pass_uv2;

void main(){
    pass_position_view = (viewModel * vec4(position_model, 1.0)).xyz;
    pass_normal_view = normalView * normal_model;
    pass_uv = uv;
    pass_uv2 = uv2;

    gl_Position = projViewModel * vec4(position_model, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 450 core

struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuseTexture;
    sampler2D specularTexture;

    vec3 diffuseColor;

    float uvScaling;
    float shininess;
    float specularIntensity;

    bool hasDiffuseTexture;
    bool hasSpecularTexture;
    bool faceSideNormalCorrection;
};

uniform Material material;

in vec3 pass_position_view;
in vec3 pass_normal_view;
in vec2 pass_uv;
in vec2 pass_uv2;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_diffuse;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 out_position;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 out_normal;

void main(){
    vec4 diffuseTextureColor = vec4(1.0);

    if(material.hasDiffuseTexture){
        diffuseTextureColor = texture(material.diffuseTexture, pass_uv * material.uvScaling);
    }

    float specularTextureIntensity = 1.0;

    if(material.hasSpecularTexture){
        specularTextureIntensity = texture(material.specularTexture, pass_uv * material.uvScaling).x;
    }

    vec3 fragNormal = pass_normal_view;
    if(material.faceSideNormalCorrection && !gl_FrontFacing){
        fragNormal = -fragNormal;
    }

    out_diffuse = vec4(diffuseTextureColor.rgb * material.diffuseColor, material.shininess);
    out_position = vec4(pass_position_view, 1.0); // Must be 1.0 on the alpha -> 0.0 = sky
    out_normal = vec4(fragNormal, material.specularIntensity * specularTextureIntensity);
}
```

Yes, I know, the eye space position is useless in the G-Buffer since you can compute it later from the depth buffer. I just did this for now but it's temporary.
Also, if anything in my shaders is deprecated or a bad practice, it would be cool if you tell me what to do instead ! Thanks !

### Additionnal infos (most of them useless I think):

1. **Camera:** *FOV* = 70°, *Ratio* = 16/9, *Near* = 0.0001, *Far* = 10
2. **OpenGL:** *Major* = 4, *Minor* = 5, *Profile* = Core
3. **Texture:** *InternalFormat* = `GL_RGBA`, *Filters* = Anisotropic, Trilinear
4. **Hardware:** *GPU* = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970, *CPU* = Interl(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz, *Memory* = 16.00 GB RAM (15.94 GB usable), *Screen* = 1920 x 1080 @ 144Hz
5. **Driver:** *GeForce Game Ready Driver V368.69 (release: 6 July 2016)*

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem with the smallest possible scenario? Like a 2x2 plane in forward shading?

Comment: Yes and it produce the sames results. Also, the closer you are to the plane, the more noticeable are the artifacts. but I think it's just a problem with the mipmap maybe ?

Comment: My bet the cause is this: High amount of repetitions means the exponent of the floating value is higher so there is less fractional bits left in the mantissa lovering the precision of texture coordinates even before normalization and interpolation ... `10000 <= 2^16` so you got at least 15 bits unusable for the fractional part from mantissa ... and the float has exponent and sign too so there are not much bits left

Comment: This seems to be the more logic reason. Please answer this question so I can validate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to floating-point imprecisions created during rasterization (interpolation, perspective correction) and worsened by the normalization in the fragment shader to fetch the correct texels.

But this is also a problem with mipmaps : to calculate which level to use, the UV of adjacent pixels are retrieved to know if the texture is stretched or compressed on screen. Because of the imprecisions, adjacent pixels share the same UV, thus the differences between them (or the 'partial derivatives') are null. This makes the `texture()` function sample the lowest mipmap level on those identical pixels, thus creating discontinuities.

Comment: Thanks ! You answered another thing I didn't understood: how OpenGL knows which mipmap level to use :D !

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246413/understanding-the-basics-of-dfdx-and-dfdy) and [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177520-Mipmap-level-calculation-using-dFdx-dFdy?p=1236952&viewfull=1#post1236952) for the actual calculation from the derivatives.

Comment: Is it possible to remove these artifacts using derivatives functions ? From what I understood, the problem is just a floating-point precision error (that can't be fixed)

Comment: Use more geometry with a smaller UV range so there is less imprecisions.